# What happens if a mimblewimble transaction gets combined into two different transactions before being posted?

Tags: mimblewimble

Let's say a couple people create Transaction A and instead of dandelioning it to just one person, they dandelioned it to 2. Let's say further than transaction A then gets combined with transaction B (creating transaction AB) AND gets combined with transaction C (creating transaction AC). If a miner receives both transaction AB and transaction AC, can they be safely combined into the blockchain, or can only one be chosen?

Comment: Are you saying that people sign ANYONECANPAY transaction and then forward it so others can add their inputs?

Comment: @Ugam Kamat The question is tagged Mimblewimble, where this kind of combining is always possible.

Comment: @PieterWuille Are you implying that the answer to my question is that AB combined with AC will create a valid ABC transaction without any problems?

Comment: @B T No, I'm not. I'm only correcting @Ugam Kamat's misunderstanding that this question was about Bitcoin.